# Can you get a hextech chest on a S rating champ?

Tags: league-of-legends

To be more specific, if I got an S rating on a champ and am not eligible to get a chest, will I get a chest if I get an S rating on the same champ when I am able to get a chest again.

Edit: What I mean by not eligible is that I have already received 4 chest for the month and now I get an S rating on say Udyr. Next month can I get a chest with the same champ I previously got an S rating on and didn't receive a chest (due to all 4 received for the previous month). I understand I would need to get an S rating again for this champ.

This is specific to earning an S rating solo and whether you can still earn a chest at a later stage because you didn't receive any chest the first time because all chests were already used previously.

Comment: Do you have your monthly limit of four chests, or did you already earn a S rank for this season on said champion or have you had any recent bans / restrictions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Hextech Crafting work?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259118/how-does-hextech-crafting-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You get a chest for receiving S grades when you have avaiable chests to be received, and are not currently considered with negative behaviour (Recent Restrictions/Bans).

That means that once you are ellegible to receive chests again you will also have to get S ranks to obtain the chests. You can't obtain S ranks, and once your punishment expires obtain the chests.

The same is valid for when you're out of chests to be gained. You can only gain another chest when you get one avaiable (You get one new available per week), even if you get S ranks.

Comment: Your last point is what I am looking for. So just to be clear, when I run out of chests and I get an S rating on a champ (and don't receive a chest). I can still get a chest the next month with the same champ by getting an S rating again.

Comment: Indeed. If you need to check which champions you've already received the chest with before you can do so at the "Champions" tab under your profile. Champions that already granted you a chest should have a differen portraitt border

Answer (score 2):

No.

Once you get a S rating on a specific champion and get a chest, you cannot receive another chest for that champion until the next season.

http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/site/2016-season-update/champion-mastery.html

Comment: You're answering : "Can I earn more than 1 chest per champion?". That is not what he asked; He asked if he can get a chest when his punishments wears off, without having to get an S rank again.

Comment: @Oak How do you know its from a ban and not from earning an S rank already?

Comment: Because the term "not elegible" is only used when referring to punishments

Comment: @Oak, eligible is an English word, not LoL jargon. Just because it is used in one way, does not mean it is disqualified in other uses. If Asker means to say 'I am not eligible for the chest as I have met the cap', for example, that is still correct use.

Comment: @Timelord64 "Not Eligible" only appears as a message under a specific set of circumstances: You get S rank, but you have been recently punished with xyz. Not having a chest will not trigger any message. In fact, is he meant that "he has no more chests to receive", wouldn't he say "will I get the chest when I get another free chest avaiable"?

Comment: @Oak, perhaps. But that havn't; in fact, asker has confirmed their intention in an edit. "What I mean by not eligible is that I have already received 4 chests this month". Nothing to do with a ban at all.

Answer (score 1):

> When you or someone in your premade party earns any S rank, you’ll acquire a chest. You can earn up to four chests each month, and each champion you play can earn you one chest per season.

Chests can be purchased in the shop for 125 RP as well.

Also note that if you are playing for example Graves in a premade team. If someone on your team gets an S the chest you receive will count towards Graves making you ineligible to receive another chest while playing Graves, not the champion they played.

You can see which champions you have or haven't earned chests for on your profile page under the champions tab.

[Source](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/site/2016-season-update/champion-mastery.html)