# How to craft Champion mastery 6-7?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have a level 5 champion mastery with Morgana, and recently received my second S rank champ token with her.  Upon going to the crafting menu, I select "Upgrade with 2 champ tokens and 1 champ permanent."  When I select that, however, it shows I have the tokens, but NOT the permanent.  I clearly own Morgana, but is that not a permanent? Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A permanent is not the ownership of the champion but what you get if you have a shard of that character and already own that character.

Source: http://boards.eune.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/champions-gameplay-en/EPcciL4P-what-is-the-difference-between-champion-shard-and-champion-permanent

Comment: Ahh thanks!  That's super confusing though.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, it's just misunderstanding. When they says "champion permanent" they are talking about the champion shard.

So, here are the 3 choices you have :

- Morgana Champion Shard
- Morgana Skin Shard
- 500 Blue essence

I recommend you to use the Champion essence as it is quite easy to optain. You can get some by disenchanting any Champion Shard or by buying a Mystery Champion Shard at 1700 IP. From that chest you get a random Champion Shard and some Blue essence. You don't need a key to open Champion Chest.

You can find more detail about Hextech crafting [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259118/how-does-hextech-crafting-work).